# Image Upload duplication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to allow users to upload three images(optional) when they make a review of the product. I am encountering a problem with the code below, which is that the images duplicate when the form is submitted which means that i sometimes get two of the same images or all three the same. Does anyone know the solution to this issue or a better way to do three image optional image uploads?

Html:

```
{{Form::label('image', 'Image(optional')}}
{{Form::file('image')}}
{{Form::label('image2', 'Image(optional')}}
{{Form::file('image2')}}
{{Form::label('image3', 'Image(optional')}}
{{Form::file('image3')}}
```

Laravel PHP:

```
 $picture = new Picture();
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
            $picture->image = $filename;
        }
        $picture->products()->associate($product);
        $picture->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $picture->reviews()->associate($review);
    $picture->save();

    $picture2 = new Picture();
    if($request->hasFile('image2')){
        $image = $request->file('image2');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $picture2->image = $filename;
    }
    $picture2->products()->associate($product);
    $picture2->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $picture2->reviews()->associate($review;

    $picture2->save();
    $picture3 = new Picture();
    if($request->hasFile('image3')){
        $image = $request->file('image3');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $picture3->image = $filename;
    }
    $picture3->products()->associate($product);
    $picture3->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $picture3->reviews()->associate($review);

    $picture3->save();
```

Comment: I think it may not about image, it's because you are using time(), and since everything happen fast, you get 3 same file name

Comment: I think you can use `uniqid` for the file name to ensure each file has unique name, something like this `$filename = uniqid('img_') . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: check this out : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-generate-long-unique-name-for-filename?page=1